# ASP.NET MVC4 routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I've searched Stack for ages, read the MSDN docs and used Bing but cannot see why this won't work! I've got the relevant code below + the routes. The route called `Browse` works just fine, but the `productCode` param for the `Details` route is always equal to nothing. If I make any mods I keep getting the 'resource not found' 404 page.

```
' Lives in controller called 'Details'
' Usage: site.com/details/abc123
Function Index(productCode As String) As ActionResult

' Lives in controller called 'Browse'    
' Usage: site.com/browse/scifi/2
Function Index(genre As String, Optional page As Integer = 1) As ActionResult
```

The routes are:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
        "Browse", _
        "{controller}/{genre}/{page}", _
        New With {.controller = "Browse", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional, .page = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )

    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Details", _
        "details/{productCode}", _
        New With {.controller = "Details", .action = "Info", .productCode = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order does matter when defining your routes.

When you request `site.com/details/abc123` I think it matches your first route.

You will get

`controller = "details"`

`action = "Index"`

`genre = "abc123"`

Which is why your productCode is null.

Switch the two `route.MapRoute` statements around, it should fix your problem.

Your second route does have action set to `info` rather than `index`, but i'm assuming that is a typo?